# Apache Spark : Cassandra Read : How to Ignore or replace '\n' character while writing to a file

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am having some column entries(string) in my cassandra which is having '\n' inside like:

> (id,name,age) values(1,'abc\nxyz',28)

Now I am using spark to write my rows in a csv file but spark is taking '\n' character as a new line

> val cass= spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").option("keyspace","mykeyspace").option("table","mytable").load
>
> cass.write.csv("abc.csv")

```
id|name|age
1|abc
xyz|28
2|gfgdd|32
```

Is there any way I can ignore or replace '\n' with blank space while writing, so that output will be

```
id|name|age
1|abcxyz or abc xyz|28
2|gfgdd|32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `functions.regexp_replace` to replace next line characters with space as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

object ReplaceNextLine {


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = List((1,"anc\nxyz",28)).toDF("id","name","age").toDF
        .withColumn("name",functions.regexp_replace(functions.col("name"),"\n"," "))

    df.show()

  }

}
```